# MIPS doubleword boundary and stack pointer

Tags: memory, stack, mips, mars-simulator

In MIPS, to store a double (8 bytes), the stack pointer `$sp` is decremented by 4:

```
addi    $sp, $sp, -4
s.d     $f10, 0($sp)
```

This doesn't make sense to me, as 8 bytes are being taken up in memory, but the stack pointer moves as if it is using a single word boundary. To store two doubles, it seems the stack pointer should be decremented by 12, not 16 as expected:

```
addi    $sp, $sp, -12
s.d     $f10, 0($sp)
s.d     $f12, 8($sp)
```

Why does this behavior occur? It then causes problems if the subroutine is called recursively (the first time is aligned, the second isn't)

**Edit**: I am running this code with MARS 4.5. `s.d $f10, 8($sp)` translates into

```
lui $1,0
addu $1,$1,$29
sdc1 $f10,8($1)
```

The stack pointer is not moved during this time. Stepping through it looks like `sdc1` puts both `$f10` and `$f11` in the stack at once.

Comment: What/who is generating this code (i.e., what/who is deciding how much to decrement the stack pointer)?  In MARS, `s.d` is a pesudo-instruction.  Perhaps looking at the pseudo-instruction expansion in the context of the complete program will help answer your question.

Comment: @Zack I have updated the original post.

Comment: I also think that the stack pointer should be decremented by 8 not 4.  What is leading you to think that 8 is not correct?

Comment: @Zack The only reason is that MARS throws an error `Runtime exception at 0x0040000c: address not aligned on doubleword boundary 0x7fffeff4` (for `addi $sp, $sp, -8`)

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the $sp just happens to be set to a value that isn't a multiple of 8.  If so, try this:  `andi $sp, $sp, 0xfffffff8`.  That should bump $sp down to the next multiple of 8.  However, you need to take care so you can properly return $sp to its original value.

Comment: I use `add $sp, $sp, -4` and `add $sp, $sp, 4`, which is essentially equivalent. The reasoning behind MARS's error is what I'm more interested in.

Comment: MIPS requires that data be "aligned".  That means that addresses of word data must be multiples of 4, and addresses of doubleword data must be multiples of 8.  Suppose $sp happens to be initialized to a multiple of 8, then you push an integer, then push a doubleword float.  The second push will cause a run-time error, because the $sp will no longer be a multiple of 8.    The `andi` above 'rounds down'; it doesn't subtract.